# Is there any boilerplate available for React and Express that contains Authentication, Authorization, Emails, and Assets management etc

Tags: node.js, react, authentication

I am looking for a boilerplate for ReactJs and ExpressJs with basic features that most of tha Web Apps use. Like Login, Signup, Forget Password, Member Invitation, Email Sending, Files Uploading/Retrieving, ORM etc.

Is there any boilerplate available? If yes, what are its pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

**For Express:**
The code repository [here](https://github.com/azat-co/practicalnode) can be used if you are looking for an express based server. 
If you are interested in typescript then, [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter) might be helpful. Another more object oriented version is [this](https://github.com/mwanago/express-typescript).